# Flutter, build for IOS : Cant see the login page on Iphone

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

Im using Flutter on Windose to create an app for Android & IOS.
I use Codemagic to build and sign my app for Apple. The first version was ok and is live on the App Store.
But I need to implemant Sign In with Apple for the next version.

Im using this package : https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple
it, and it works good on android, a webpage opens and I can login and get back user session..

For Apple, compilation is fine, it is pushed on Apple servers and I get the app on Testflight, but impossible to make it works, the login page is never called.

As I understand, I need to ad the "Sign in with Apple" capability.
But without XCode, I cant figure how to do that!!

Is it possible to edit the info.plist, or another file, to add this capability?
I have build and change already all the certificates, profiles... on apple console, to add the Sign In with Apple, but same result!

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Are you completed all steps from plugin's tutorial?

Comment: Yes I did, except for the part in Your App : First and foremost make sure that your app has the "Sign in with Apple" capability (Runner (file browser side bar) -> Targets -> Runner -> Signing & Capabilities), as otherwise Sign in with Apple will fail without visual indication (the code will still receive exceptions) as i dont have XCode and I dont know how to do without!!

Answer (score 1):

with Codemagic you can connect to a build machine and use Xcode to update project settings and push the changes back to the repository.

1. Install VNC Viewer on your machine
2. Start a new build (I'd recommend using Mac Pro instance type as Xcode requires more resources)
3. When the build has started, click `Explore build machine` above the build steps to see the instructions for setting up VNC access. Use the given `Host`, `Port`, `Username` and `Password` on your VNC client to establish the connection.

read more here https://blog.codemagic.io/remote-access-to-virtual-mac-build-machine/